# Driver side front door window doesn't work

Tags: nissan, power-windows, altima

I have a Nissan Altima 2008 3.5 SE. The driver's door power-window doesn't work using the button on the door panel. However, if it works when a key is inserted in the door lock and rotated clockwise.

Also, when there is a rain or if I pour some water where the power-window slides in, the button on the door panel works.

I want to fix this myself. Before I open the door, I wanted to know where the issue would be. Is it a loose connection? Or does the motor required greasing?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely there's an issue with the window switch.

Comment: Thank you @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I will look for the window switch. However, I'm still confused because when there is a rain (due to which water will gets inside the door shell) or if manually water is poured, the switch works. So is it a loose connection which is shorted with water droplets?

Comment: You need to remove the door panel and inspect/test the wiring and components. Don’t buy a switch until you can confirm thats the reason why.